# flutter get pdf files string data to variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to take a pdf files string data in a fast way and the package which I use is giving some problems.
How can I get correctly and fast way a pdf file?
Thanks for your help.

this is the way ı using

```
  PDFDoc? _pdfDoc;
  String _text = "";

  _getPdfFile() {
    setState(() async {
      _pdfDoc = await PDFDoc.fromPath(filePath!);
      data = await _pdfDoc!.text;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the source of code. this code will take string data from the pdf page 3.
Instead, if you want all the data in pdf you can look at this link.https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-text-extraction

```
final String data; 
    final PdfDocument document =
          PdfDocument(inputBytes: myFile.readAsBytesSync());

      setState(() {
        data = PdfTextExtractor(document).extractText(startPageIndex: 3);
      });

      document.dispose();
```